# How to Convert SQL query to LINQ (to get last record each bookingStatus)

Tags: c#, linq, ef-core-6.0

Need some help translating below query to LINQ.

```
;With BookingWithLastStatus 
as
(
    Select *, Rnk = ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by BookingId order by Id desc)
    from BookingStatus
)
 
Select * 
from BookingWithLastStatus
where Rnk=1 AND StatusId = 3
```

I've done LINQ below but it is not getting the correct records.

```
var BookStatus = from p in _context.Set<BookingStatus>()
   where p.StatusId == 3
   group p by p.BookingId into opt
   select new {
       BookingId = opt.Key,
       Id = opt.Max(x => x.Id)
   };
```

The SQL query is getting 1 record only which is correct and my LINQ is getting multiple records.

UPDATE:

I did like this:

Get all the BookingStatus first

```
var GetAllBookStatus = await _context.Set<BookingStatus>() 
.ToListAsync();
```

Then do the filtering based from the SQL Query I need.

```
                var FilteredBookStatus = GetAllBookStatus
                    .OrderByDescending( x => x.Id )
                    .GroupBy(person => person.BookingId)   
                    .Select( group => new { Group = group, Count = group.Count() } )
                    .SelectMany( groupWithCount =>
                        groupWithCount.Group.Select( b => b)
                        .Zip(
                            Enumerable.Range( 1, groupWithCount.Count ),
                            ( b, i ) => new { 
                                b.Id,
                                b.BookingId,
                                b.BookingMWABId, 
                                b.BookStatus,
                                b.CreatedBy,
                                b.CreatedDate,
                                b.Destination,
                                b.InternalStatus,
                                b.LineNum,
                                b.ModifiedBy,
                                b.ModifiedDate,
                                b.Module,
                                b.ReasonCode,
                                b.ReceivedBy,
                                b.RefNo,
                                b.StatusId,
                                b.TimeStamp,
                                RowNumber = i }
                        )
                    )
                    .Where(a => a.StatusId == 3 && a.RowNumber == 1)
                    .ToList();
```

But I'm not so confident on Getting all records, as it will grow some time. Is there anything I can change from my code?

Comment: Can you try to provide sample data? [Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/26Xvej78ta4582uaPk8nqH/0), I try your script with some sample data, but it doesn't seems will return only 1 record.

Comment: @YongShun actually, your demo is correct. If I execute the LINQ with your sample data, it gets everything. Because I don't know how to get the `Rnk=1` just like in the SQL.

Comment: The difference is that your first query only gets `BookingStatus` records if the ones with `StatusId = 3` also happen to rank first. I think the SQL query should have `from BookingStatus WHERE StatusId = 3` in the CTE (and then remove `AND StatusId = 3`).

Comment: I updated my question @GertArnold, I can now retrieved what I need. Can you check what can I improve in my code?

Comment: So the SQL query is correct? I.e. you want the  `BookingStatus`es where the first one within `BookingId` has StatusId = 3? Also, which type of LINQ is this? Entity Framework? And which version?

Comment: @GertArnold yes, the query is correct. Entity Framework. I'm using 6.0.3 version.

Comment: Thinking that you can do like this [demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/aJLAmJ). Concept query BookingStatus where subquery (To get Max Id by BookingId) contains Id.

Comment: @YongShun the demo you provided is running fine. Thank you for that. However, I edited 1 record from this [link]https://dotnetfiddle.net/lGpvuk demo, the `bookingId 1` has 3 record, which has the max id of 3 with the latest `StatusId is 2`. It should not include in the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With EF core 6.x, you can do the following. It is not optimal case as in your SQL, but should work:

```cs
var BookStatus = 
    from p in _context.Set<BookingStatus>()
    group p by p.BookingId into g
    select g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).First();

BookStatus = BookStatus.Where(p => p.StatusId == 3);
```

Or another variant

```cs
var BookStatus = _context.Set<BookingStatus>().AsQueryable();

BookStatus = 
    from d in BookStatus.Select(d => new { d.BookingId }).Distinct()
    from p in BookStatus
        .Where(p => p.BookingId == d.BookingId)
        .OrderByDescending(p => p.Id)
        .Take(1)
    select p;

BookStatus = BookStatus.Where(p => p.StatusId == 3);
```

Comment: As I understood from the comments, they only want the results of which the record with highest `Id` *also* has `StatusId == 3`.

Comment: @GertArnold, you are right, my fault. Fixed.

Comment: @GertArnold I like your solution, but it got an error where it says "The LINQ expression 'GroupByShaperExpression:\r\nKeySelector: b.BookingId, \r\nElementSelector:EntityShaperExpression: \r\n    EntityType: BookingStatus\r\n    ValueBufferExpression: \r\n        ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember\r\n    IsNullable: False\r\n\r\n    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Id)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'.

Comment: Strange, should work. Anyway, added another query.